# Vue Test Utils / apollo-composable check if useMutation was called

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vue-test-utils, vue-apollo

I have the component AddEmployeeModal.vue where I want to test if UseMutation from vue/apollo-composable gets called

```ts
// AddEmployeeModal.vue:
import { provideApolloClient, useMutation, useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { apolloClient } from '@/apollo/ApolloClient';
import {
  CreateEmployeeDocument,
  UpdateEmployeeDocument,
} from '@/generated/graphql';

provideApolloClient(apolloClient);

const { mutate: addEmployee } = useMutation(CreateEmployeeDocument);
const { mutate: updateEmployee } = useMutation(UpdateEmployeeDocument);
```

I think I need to mock the useMutation function but I'm not sure how to mock a library function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

jest.mock('@vue/apollo-composable', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useQuery: jest.fn(),
  useMutation: jest.fn()
}))
useQuery.mockImplementation(() => ({
  result: { value: testRes }
}))
useMutation.mockImplementation(() => ({
  onDone: jest.fn()
}))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).